# Python-Selenium - if else statement to check element visibility and clicking if available

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using below code to check element visibility and click if available.

if element is available it is clicking quickly and moving to next code.

Problem: 
if element is not visible/available it is taking more to time to skip and move to next code.

i understand it may take some time.

Question is:
is there any way to perform quickly if element not visible or if any other code to perform my test case quickly.

```
elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("<element>")

if not elements:

   print("Element Not Found")

else:

   element = elements[0]

   element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your code, you are interested only on the first link (elements[0]), you can restrict the driver to find the first link only using below method

```
find_element_by_partial_link_text
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.
My Scenario: Login to webapplication. sometime sample button will be visible and sometime not. 
i am planning to handle that if element is visible click or skip and go to next code. in your code if element is visible it will click otherwise it will fail with nosuchelement exception.
Hope you got myquestion

Comment: My Scenario: Login to webapplication. sometime sample button will be visible and sometime not. i am planning to handle that if element is visible click or skip and go to next code.
in your code if element is visible it will click otherwise it will fail with nosuchelement exception

Comment: you can handle that with proper try and except

Comment: i tried. it is also taking time. is this time consumption is expected?
1) is_displayed() - Not working if element is not visible.
2) try and except is also taking more time to move next code if element is not visible. 
3) if and else with array kind of thing also taking more time to move next code if element is not visible. if any other option or method please let me know.